# Why Scilab does not show 3D plots?

Tags: scilab

I'm new to scilab so working out basics.Below script opens the graphics window shows the empty box.I guess a straight line should be shown for these x,y,z points  which doesn't show up here.Why is that so?

```
x=linspace(1,100)
y=linspace(1,100)
z=linspace(1,100)
plot3d(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot3d` plots surfaces, and you give it 3 vectors instead of matrices. With 3 vectors you can plot a (parametric) curve in 3 dimensions with `param3d`:

```
x=linspace(1,100)
y=linspace(1,100)
z=linspace(1,100)
param3d(x,y,z)
```